# Do I have to study Complex Analysis before Hermitian Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, hermitian-matrices

When I taught myself linear algebra using some textbooks I found that Hermitian Matrix has been mentioned quite a few times; and I see Hermitian Matrix has applications in statistics (time series analysis, etc), which is the field I have some interests in.

I've done some google search but I couldn't really find any close/direct connection between Hermitian Matrix and Complex Analysis (apart from Hermitian Function which is part of Complex Function Theory). I might have asked google incorrectly though.

As Hermitian Matrix is a complex square matrix, do I have to study Complex Analysis in order to fully understand it?

Comment: Short answer: no. You just need to know arithmetic in the complex numbers, nothing too fancy.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! it is reassuring, I can, at least, leave Complex Analysis until later :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. While you can do some interesting things with Hermitian matrices if you know complex analysis, you really don't need it. A knowledge of linear algebra and basic arithmetic on complex numbers should be enough to get into some good results.

Comment: Thanks for the good news :P in a way that I can do Complex Analysis later on hehe